# Why are the images popping up and then it fades out

Tags: javascript, html, fadein, fadeout, sliding

**[Website to review](https://www.sorensonvrs.com/index_cl)**

I have 6 images to fade in/out, but the first 5 images pops up as if they're trying to load the images before the sliding images works. Watch the first 5 image pop up and then it fades out and in as it is working. I want them to fade in and out right from the beginning without popping them up. Whats causing this?

Dont worry about the `id="liSlider"` part. It just the padding in css.

Javascript -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

   setInterval(function() {
   $('#slideshow > div:first')
   .fadeOut(5000)
   .next()
   .fadeIn(5000)
   .end()
   .appendTo('#slideshow');
   }, 5000);
</script>
```

HTML -

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div id="liSlider"><a href="{base_url}ntouchdesktop"><img src="{base_url}assets/images/svrsv2/SVRS_Homepage-Slide_2.png"></a></div>
    <div id="liSlider"><a href="https://www.sorenson.com/wavello" target="_blank"><img src="{base_url}assets/images/svrsv2/SVRS_Homepage-Slide_1.png"></a></div>
    <div id="liSlider"><a href="{base_url}ntouchmobile"><img src="{base_url}assets/images/svrsv2/SVRS_Homepage-Slide_5.png"></a></div>
    <div id="liSlider"><a href="{base_url}ntouchdesktop"><img src="{base_url}assets/images/svrsv2/SVRS_Homepage-Slide_6.png"></a></div>
    <div id="liSlider"><a href="{base_url}ntouchmobile"><img src="{base_url}assets/images/svrsv2/SVRS_Homepage-Slide_3.png" ></a></div>
    <div id="liSlider"><a href="{base_url}ntouchmobile"><img src="{base_url}assets/images/svrsv2/SVRS_Homepage-Slide_4.png"></a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Threw the code in a fiddle and it seems to be working as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/7pd4uxq6/1/? It might be something in your CSS? Just a note on the `id="liSlider"`. IDs can't / aren't meant to be repeated, you want to make those `class="liSlider"`

Comment: Thank you, I changed id to class and the images still pops up. I dont think it has to do with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS to hide all the slides and then fade the first one in on load.

Updated demo: https://jsfiddle.net/7pd4uxq6/3/

CSS

```
#slideShow {
  position: relative;
}

.liSlider { // note class
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

JS

```
$('#slideshow > div:first').fadeIn(500) // updated

setInterval(function() {
   $('#slideshow > div:first')
   .fadeOut(5000)
   .next()
   .fadeIn(5000)
   .end()
   .appendTo('#slideshow');
}, 5000);
```